# ls: cannot access nav.php: Structure needs cleaning

Tags: files, filesystems, directory-structure

I have a problem with one file, which is located in my /var/www/html order on my raspberry pi which runs apache2 and php.

Before I restarted my pi, the file was totaly normal reachable. Now I got the following message, when I enter the directory and execute the command ls.

```
ls: cannot access nav.php: Structure needs cleaning
```

What does this mean? I can also not `cat` or anything else doing with that file. Of course I can recreate the file under a new filename, but I want to know, what was going wrong.

Thanks for every response.